# Organic molecules with 21.62% oxygen

Tags: organic-chemistry, elemental-analysis

I have been told to answer the following question:

> Seven different compounds, all either alcohols or ethers,
>   contained 21.62% oxygen. Find the structural formula for all of these compounds and name the alcohols.

So far I've tried using empirical formula calculations to work out a simple formula but this has yielded no results because I do not know the exact ratio of hydrogen to carbon in the formula nor do I know any masses which I could use to scale up the empirical formula into a molecular formula. It seems to me that there just isn't enough information to answer the question - after hours of searching I can't even find one, let alone seven. I'm sure the answer is stupidly easy but it's evaded me. Does anyone have any suggestions of things I might be able to try? This question is UK A-Level standard.

Comment: I am not sure if the precision that is implied in the question is correct. For example, butanol actually contains 21.58 % oxygen, which is suspiciously close to the given 21.62 %.

Comment: With this many significant digits, check the atomic weights used in this 21.62% figure.  Do they agree with your sources also to four significant digits?  If not you may be chasing your tail.

Comment: I also get butanol using empirical formulas. Note that UK A-Level uses one decimal place atomic masses.

Comment: "Alcohols or ethers," assuming no double bonds, suggests a structural formula $\ce{C_nH_{2n+2}O}$. Find the percentage of oxygen in such a compound as a function of $n$, set it equal to 21.62%, then solve for $n$. If a non-integral solution emerges, assume one double bond and repeat, etc. Then form seven isomers from the identified structural formula.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Disclaimer*:

Here I take the molar masses of carbon, hydrogen and oxygen to be $\pu{12g, 1g, 16g}$ respectively, which is what would be expeccted of you at school.

---

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume you have $\pu{100g}$ of the said compound. Which would mean it contains $\pu{21.62g}$ of oxygen.

Employing a bit of basic math in the analysis of that fact, leads us to similar (but more useful) re-statement:

> $\pu{74g}$ of the said compound will contain $\pu{16g}$ of oxygen (the number also being the same as the *molar mass* of oxygen).

---

Now our substance possess a general formula of $\ce{C_{x}H_{y}O_{z}}$.

So in $\pu{74g}$ of it (of which $\pu{16g}$ is oxygen), the molar masses of $\pu{C}$ ( times the number of moles of it, which is $x$ ) and $\pu{H}$ ( times the number of moles of it, which is $y$ ) must add up to $\pu{74-16=58}$. Which gives us the equation:

$$\ce{x(12) + y(1) = 58}$$

Now neither $x$ nor $y$ can carry the value $\pu{0}$ (else we won't be dealing with a hydrocarbon anymore). This gives us three mathematically (not necessarily *physically*) plausible options:

1. $\pu{x= 2; y= 34}$
2. $\pu{x= 3; y= 22}$
3. $\pu{x= 4; y= 10}$

Even if you've only just started studying organic chem. you should be able to tell that the first two options are *absolutely* ridiculous (that's way too many hydrogen atoms that can be accommodated around 2 or 3 carbon atoms). So we go with the third option: $\pu{x= 4; y= 10}$, which sounds promising.

Which gives us the formula  $\ce{C_{4}H_{10}O}$

---

You may now work out what alcohols or ethers that could give you ;-)

> [image]